# What is the 'loading' return value from useSession() in next-auth?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm writing a Next.js project, and implementing authentication using GitHub and `next-auth`. In the examples of `next-auth`, there's a call to `useSession()`, which returns two objects: `session` and `loading`. However, none of the examples that I've seen actually use the `loading` object.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { 
  useSession, 
  signin, 
  signout 
} from 'next-auth/client'

export default () => {
  const [ session, loading ] = useSession()

  return <p>
    {!session && <>
      Not signed in <br/>
      <button onClick={signin}>Sign in</button>
    </>}
    {session && <>
      Signed in as {session.user.email} <br/>
      <button onClick={signout}>Sign out</button>
    </>}
  </p>
}
```

**Question**: What is the purpose of `loading`, and how is it used in practice?

Answer (score 9):

The `loading` option indicates the session state is being updated; it is `true` when session data is being fetched and `false` when it is done checking.

It's slightly complex as the `session` property can be populated already even if it's loading (e.g. because it already has a cached value it can use from a previous call), so technically `session` can be populated even when `loading` is `true`.

If using the NextAuth.js provider in `pages/_app.js` the `session` object returned from `useSession` can also be populated if `getSession()` has been called in `getInitialProps()` or `getServerSideProps()`.

If you have an active session, actions like the window gaining or losing focus will cause NextAuth.js to check the session state again in the background, to try and make sure it's not stale.

tl;dr

When you check `loading` you probably also want to check `session` is not `null` first. If the `session` state is an object, the user has a valid session and you don't need to wait for `loading` to return.

However, if `session` is `null` and `loading` is `false` then they definitely don't have an active session.

Comment: I was expecting `loading` to be `true` after `signIn()` is being called. I wanted to use it to show a spinner on the login-submit-button while `signIn()` did its thing.

**But I had to learn that `signIn()`** (and also `singOut()`) **does not have any effect on `loading`.**

Probably I'm having a major misunderstanding. Maybe someone can clear the fog for me ..

Comment: @Tobi I think that is a fair assumption! I'm not sure that it does, but it seems entirely reasonable to expect and if it's not happening I think we could change it. Calling either `signIn()` or `signOut()` *should* change the current session state, but - as you say - I'm not sure that it does actually change the `loading` value.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own loading functionality by creating your own useState:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);;

function handleGoogleLogIn() {
  signIn("google");
  setGoogleLoading(true);
}
```

and then in your html

```
{ loading && (<div> your loading spinner or anything...</div>) }
```