# Next.js: Adding next-i18next to a project that uses next-auth

Tags: next.js, next-auth, next-i18next

## One-sentence summary

When I have [`await serverSideTranslations`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-i18next) inside `getStaticProps`, `loading` value from [`useSession()`](https://next-auth.js.org/v3/getting-started/client#usesession) remains stuck as `true`.

## Context

I use [`next-auth.js`](https://next-auth.js.org/v3/getting-started/client#usesession) (v3) for auth. I have (gratefully) used this for a year without a problem.

`const [session, loading]` = [`useSession()`](https://next-auth.js.org/v3/getting-started/client#usesession) is a hook to check if someone is signed in.

> The `loading` option indicates the session state is being updated; it is `true` when session data is being fetched and `false` when it is done checking.
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/63191786/870121

I'm adding [`next-i18next`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-i18next) to my project. Most of it's working, but I'm having some difficulty.

I've followed the instructions and [example code](https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next/blob/ee5965183436d9b13d85c9187b3e09983b34ce7f/examples/simple/pages/second-page.js) for `next-i18next`.

**It works well on pages with `getServerSideProps`**: pages load, next-auth's `useSession()` still works, and translations work without warning or errors (example).
For example, `/login` uses `getServerSideProps` like this:

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const { locale } = context;
  console.log("Have locale, ", locale);
  return {
    props: {
      csrfToken: await csrfToken(context),
      ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, ["common", "login"])),
    },
  };
};
```

and works well for [/de/login](https://awesound-web-iow8f7d1o-awesound.vercel.app/de/login)  and [/en/login or just /login](https://awesound-web-iow8f7d1o-awesound.vercel.app/en/login)
You might spy the word "loading…" briefly appear in the top-left of the nav bar (on desktop) on those two pages. This appears while `loading` is true, but then it quickly disappears.
[image: Spy "loading…" text appear in nav bar while 'loading' variable is true.]

## Problem

**I'm running into some difficulty when I use it with `getStaticProps`.** Specifically, `loading` returned by `useSession()` remains `true`.

Case A:
When I have this code at page-level, translations work, but 'loading' value useSession() remains true

```
export const getStaticProps = async ({ locale }) => {
  const mood = "determined";
  return {
    props: {
      mood,
      ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, ["common", "test-page"])),
    },
  };
};
```

Note the use of `await` before `serverSideTranslations` there; that's deliberate, as advised in all [the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-i18next) I've seen.

The above causes this line to not work as expected; `loading` stays stuck on `true`… hence I don't know if the user is logged in.

```
import { useSession } from "next-auth/client";

const MyComponent = ()=>{
  const [session, loading] = useSession();
  return <div>loading is {loading ? "true" : "false"}</div>
}
```

Something about the `await serverSideTranslations` is causing `useSession()` to always return `[undefined, true]`.

Note: I'm using next-auth v3, not v4.

Case B:
I can remove the `await` keyword before `serverSideTranslations`, and then `useSession()` works as normal… but then translations don't work.

Any tips?

#### What I've tried so far:

I've focused on trying to adapt `next-i18next` to not need the `await` keyword.
That took me down a rabbit hole of successive warnings/errors, each caused by the previous fix:

- Remove "await" before `serverSideTranslations` in `getStaticProps`.
- Try adding `react: { useSuspense: false }` to next-i18next.config.js per https://stackoverflow.com/a/69311205/870121 (didn't help).
- Get error `react-i18next:: You will need to pass in an i18next instance by using initReactI18next`. → Try fixing by adding `use: [initReactI18next],` to `next-i18next.config.js`.
- Get error, "appWithTranslation called without config" → fix by adding to `_app.js`

  ```js
     import nextI18NextConfig from "../../next-i18next.config.js";

     // in page-level components:
     ...(await serverSideTranslations(
       locale,
       ["common", "login"],
       nextI18NextConfig
     )),

     // in pages/_app.js
     export default appWithTranslation(AwesoundApp, nextI18NextConfig);
  ```
- Get errors like "Error: Error serializing `._nextI18Next.userConfig.use[0].init` returned from `getStaticProps`;" → Add `serializeConfig=false` to next-i18next.config.js and pass config in to `appWithTranslation` as per ["Unserialisable configs" instructions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-i18next).
  None of the `next-i18next` docs recommend removing the `await` keyword though, so this feels like a losing battle / might introduce some unintended consequences

#### What I'd like help with:

Can I leave the `await` keyword before `serverSideTranslations` in the `getStaticProps` call, but still have `loading` not stuck on `true`?
Can I leave my use of `next-i18next` as advised by those docs, but modify my `nextauth` hooks somehow so `loading` isn't stuck on true? Am I just missing some `await` keyword elsewhere in my code?

## Example code

Compare these two pages:

- [/de/test/no-await](https://awesound-web-iow8f7d1o-awesound.vercel.app/de/test/no-await) → translations don't work.
- [/de/test/with-await](https://awesound-web-iow8f7d1o-awesound.vercel.app/de/test/with-await) → translations work, but `loading` is stuck on `true`, I don't know if user is signed in.

To be clear: We want `loading` to quickly become `false`.

Those two pages have the following code.

`next.config.js` (extract):

```js
const webpack = require("webpack");
const { i18n } = require("./next-i18next.config");

const moduleExports = {
  i18n, // see require import above
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    config.resolve.fallback = {
      perf_hooks: false, // as per "Quick Solution" on https://dev.to/marcinwosinek/how-to-add-resolve-fallback-to-webpack-5-in-nextjs-10-i6j
      fs: false, // 2022-02-02 hack to fix i18n errors, per https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next/issues/935#issuecomment-970024608
      path: false, // 2022-02-02 hack to fix i18n errors, per https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next/issues/935#issuecomment-970024608
    };
    return config;
  },
  …
}
```

`next-i18next.config.js` (in its entirety):

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    defaultLocale: "en",
    locales: ["en", "de"],
    localePath: path.resolve("./public/locales"),
  },
  // react: { useSuspense: false },
  // useSuspense false does NOT prevent the warning,
  // "react-i18next:: You will need to pass in an i18next instance by using initReactI18next"  on pages that use getStaticProps and serverSideTranslations
  // per https://stackoverflow.com/a/69311205/870121
  // We only get this initReactI18next error when we do NOT use await before serverSideTranslations.
  debug: true,
};
```

`pages/with-await.jsx` (in its entirety):
See https://awesound-web-iow8f7d1o-awesound.vercel.app/de/test/with-await

```js
// Similar to https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next/blob/ee5965183436d9b13d85c9187b3e09983b34ce7f/examples/simple/pages/second-page.js
// This has getStaticProps but not getStaticPaths
// Using 'await' with serverSideTranslations breaks next-auth useSession()

import Layout from "../../components/layout";
import { serverSideTranslations } from "next-i18next/serverSideTranslations";
import TranslationTestContent from "../../components/test/translationTest";

const usesAwait = true;

const TestPage = ({ mood }) => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <TranslationTestContent mood={mood} usesAwait={usesAwait} />
    </Layout>
  );
};

export const getStaticProps = async ({ locale }) => {
  const mood = "determined";
  return {
    props: {
      mood,
      ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, ["common", "test-page"])),
    },
  };
};

export default TestPage;
```

`pages/no-await.jsx` (in its entirety):
See https://awesound-web-iow8f7d1o-awesound.vercel.app/de/test/no-await
Note it's the same as `pages/with-await.jsx` but usesAwait is false

```js
// Similar to https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next/blob/ee5965183436d9b13d85c9187b3e09983b34ce7f/examples/simple/pages/second-page.js
// This has getStaticProps but not getStaticPaths
// Using 'await' with serverSideTranslations breaks next-auth useSession()

import Layout from "../../components/layout";
import { serverSideTranslations } from "next-i18next/serverSideTranslations";
import TranslationTestContent from "../../components/test/translationTest";

const usesAwait = false;

const TestPage = ({ mood }) => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <TranslationTestContent mood={mood} usesAwait={usesAwait} />
    </Layout>
  );
};

export const getStaticProps = async ({ params, locale }) => {
  const mood = "determined";
  return {
    props: {
      mood,
      ...serverSideTranslations(locale, ["common", "test-page"]),
    },
  };
};

export default TestPage;
```

Shared component,

```js
import { useTranslation } from "next-i18next";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/client";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import ExclamationTriangleIcon from "../icons/exclamationTriangle";
import CheckCircleIcon from "../icons/checkCircle";

const TranslationTestContent = ({ mood, usesAwait = true }) => {
  const [session, loading] = useSession({ required: true });
  const { locale } = useRouter();
  const { t } = useTranslation("test-page");

  return (
    <main className="p-12">
      <div className="">Test static page with getStaticProps</div>
      <div className="">Do a full page refresh if you make any changes.</div>
      <h1>This page uses await: {usesAwait ? "yes" : "no"}</h1>
      <div>
        {usesAwait ? (
          <>
            Result: translations work, but the `loading` stays true; we don't
            know if user is logged in.
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            Result: translations don't work, but the `loading` does become
            false.
          </>
        )}
      </div>
      <h3>Test translation</h3>
      <div className="p-4 bg-seco-200 m-4 flex space-x-6">
        <div>locale: {locale}</div>
        <div>language: {t("language")}</div>
        <div>
          {t("language") === "language" ? (
            <ExclamationTriangleIcon />
          ) : (
            <CheckCircleIcon />
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
      <Link href="/">
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-prim">
          {t("Test page button")}
        </button>
      </Link>
      <h3 className="mt-12">
        Test <pre className="inline">`loading`</pre>
      </h3>
      <div className="p-4 bg-seco-200 m-4">
        <div className="flex space-x-2 items-center">
          <pre className="inline">loading</pre>:{" "}
          <span className="inline">{loading ? "true" : "false"}</span>
          {loading ? <ExclamationTriangleIcon /> : <CheckCircleIcon />}
        </div>
        <div>
          <pre className="inline">session</pre> exists?{" "}
          <span className="inline">{session ? "true" : "false"}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="border p-2 overflow-x-scroll">
        session: {JSON.stringify(session)}
      </div>
      <h3>Look at other props</h3>
      <div className="flex space-x-1 gap-x-1">
        Via <pre>props</pre>, we have <pre>mood</pre> = <pre>[{mood}]</pre>.
      </div>
    </main>
  );
};

export default TranslationTestContent;
```

Comment: might be this is an issue in useSession... did you create an issue on the github repo? https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next/issues but provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Adrai. I started a new blank project with next-auth v4 and next-i18next here: https://github.com/markitics/next-auth-with-i18n. As noted in README, if you're signed in, then clicking on a route with `serverSideTranslations` causes user to appear logged out. If I refresh the page, I'm logged in again (no need to click "Sign in").

Comment: Posted issue in github as recommended: https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next/issues/1680 I'm not sure if I need to change something with my `next-auth` integration, or with `next-i18next`.